# How to make form validations in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm trying to make form validations so that certain fields only accept certain types of inputs, such as names only accept letters and phone numbers only accept 10 numbers. I tried making a validation for the first name, as shown below:

```
#forms.py

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
# STEP 1 FORM
    student_id = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Student ID")
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="First Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Last Name")
    ssn = USSocialSecurityNumberField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="SSN", help_text="Format: xxx-xx-xxxx")
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Gender", choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Date of birth", help_text="Format: yyyy-mm-dd")
    contact_number = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Contact number")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Address")
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="City")
    state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, initial="NJ", label="State")
    zipcode = USZipCodeField(label="Zipcode")
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=countries, label="Country", initial="US")
    home_phone = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Home phone")
    cell_phone = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Cell phone")
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), max_length=254, validators=[validate_email], label="Email")
    background = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BACKGROUND_CHOICES, label="Background")
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, initial="south_plainfield", label="Location")
    workforce = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WORKFORCE_CHOICES, initial="--", label="Workforce")
    source = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, initial="individual", label="Source")
    refer_by = forms.ChoiceField(choices=REFER_BY_CHOICES, initial="no refer", label="Refer by")
    last_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LAST_STATUS_CHOICES, initial="followup", label="Last status")
    newsletter = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), label="Newsletter", required=False)
    created_by = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Created by")
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Date", help_text="Format: yyyy-mm-dd")
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=False, label="notes", help_text="less than 1000 characters")

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        first_name = cleaned_data.get('first_name')

        if first_name.isalpha == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a real name.')
        elif first_name[0].isupper() == False or first_name[1:].isupper() == True:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please capitalize properly')
        else:
            cleaned_data['first_name'] = first_name

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'ssn', 'gender', 'dob', 'contact_number', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'country', 'home_phone', 'cell_phone', 'email', 'background', 'location', 'workforce', 'source', 'refer_by', 'last_status', 'newsletter', 'created_by', 'date', 'notes')
```

However, when submitting the form, it completely ignores it and my DB Browser shows that a name with a number in it can be accepted. Is there something I wrote incorrectly, or do I have to change some code in other places besides the forms.py? I feel like if I can solve this one validation the other ones should be easier, but if someone can tell me the correct way of making sure that a phone number in a form is only 10 numbers, that would be great as well. Thanks.

Comment: The form is not the right place to do this if your goal is to force this on database level. Use validators for this in your model. Also you should define verbose names and `max_length` for your fields in your model. Then you don't have to redefine every field your model has in the form. You can just use the fields property of the form meta class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call method isalpha:

```
if first_name.isalpha == False:
```

You create a built-in method object isalpha, which is not False ever.
I think that's just a typo, write so:

```
if first_name.isalpha():
    ... # your code
```

For validation of phone number use method clean_phone:

```
def clean_phone(self):
    phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
    if not phone.isdigit():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Phone number can only contains digits')
    elif len(phone) != 10:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Length of phone number must be 10 digits')
    return phone
```

**EDIT**

That's absolutely right, you don't have to describe fields in your forms.py file, you should do it in models.py, but some special ones, like first_name must contain only letters you can describe in forms.py.

Firstly, create a Student model in models.py with all db constraints (field types, max length, choices, unique values and etc.) Take into account that django creates id field automatically.

```
# models.py

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Type of gender field depends on type of keys you used in GENDER_CHOICES
    # CharField for chars, IntegerField for integers
    gender = models.CharField(choices = GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=5)
    ...
    # Here you could validate your phone number length
    # But you still have to check it for valide symbols (in forms.py)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    # and so on for all your fields
```

After that, define your StudetForm in forms.py. You don't have to describe all you Student fields with their constraints.

```
# forms.py

from models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__' # Django adds all fields you've described in Student
        # Then you could rename you fields labels, otherwise django will use names of model fields
        labels = {
            'first_name': 'First Name',
            'last_name': 'Last Name',
            ...
        }
        # And you also can override widgets for rendering.
        # This feature could be useful for dates, because django default widget for DateField is TextInput.
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.SelectDateWidget,
        }
    
    # Now you could describe all validation methods
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if not first_name.isalpha():
            raise ValidationError('First name must contain only letters')
        return first_name
```

Comment: It still isn't validating. I read the comment about not putting this in the forms.py, but I don't know if that's the correct solution since putting 'form' in the model raises an error.

Comment: You define the model first. Igors example is great. The form is using the information defined in the model (Datatype, max_length etc.) The "clean_"- "methods" then just have to contain special checks for specific columns.